# Ant: read filenames, create folder based on names, move files into folders

Tags: regex, file-io, ant

Using Ant tasks, I want to read all filenames in a directory and copy each of the files into one folder, with the folder name the same as the file but without the extension.

Starting with:

```
converted/aa_aa.dita
converted/bb_bb.dita
converted/cc_cc.dita
```

and ending up with:

```
aa_aa/aa_aa.dita
bb_bb/bb_bb.dita
cc_cc/cc_cc.dita
```

and so on.

So far I've got this, which reads the filenames with their path and puts them in a .txt file:

```
<target name="move_dita_to_folder">
  <pathconvert pathsep=","
    property="my.files">
   <path>
     <fileset dir=".">
       <include name="*.dita"/>
     </fileset>
   </path>
 </pathconvert>

<echo file="my.files.txt" append="true">
my.files=${my.files}</echo>
```

This makes a file containing the filenames contained in the full path, separated by commas.

**Update:**

Now I have this extracting the filenames from the txt file and rewriting the txt file to put each of them on a new line:

```
   <replaceregexp byline="false" flags="gis">
     <regexp pattern="(C:)(.*?)converted\\(.*?).dita"/>
     <substitution expression="${line.separator}\3"/>
     <fileset dir=".">
     <include name="**/*.txt"/>
     </fileset>
   </replaceregexp>
```

The result being:

```
    my files=
aa_aa
bb_bb
cc_cc
```

So now I need to use those to create folder names, and copy the files into the appropriate ones.

I saw  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219029/using-mapper-fileset-to-copy-files-into-a-different-subdirectory) about using regex and mapper however which seems like a better way-- but I can't replicate what's being described there at all. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you use [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)? You can use the `<for>` task for this. Or, you can try this with `<macrodef/>`.

Comment: I'm reading about for tasks but not sure yet how to do this, could you elaborate? I'

Comment: I'm reading about for tasks but not sure yet how to do this, could you elaborate? The solution below with the script works perfectly for one directory containing .dita files. I'm curious now to see about doing it with other structures, e.g. topfolder/subfolder/aa_aa.dita   to end up with  topfolder/subfolder/aa_aa/aa_aa.dita  So basically just inserting a folder named after the .dita file, containing the file. If I run the  script below and include subfolders by using `**/*.dita`, the results get very scrambled.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a nested scriptmapper with builtin (since Java 1.6.0_06) javascript engine :

```
<copy todir="..." verbose="true">
 <fileset dir="..." includes="**/*.dita"/>
 <scriptmapper language="javascript">
  self.addMappedName(source.replace(source.split('.')[0], source.split('.')[0] + "/" + source.split('.')[0]));
 </scriptmapper>
</copy>
```

Comment: Your first one worked perfectly, this new one -- the simplified version I assume -- works perfectly also! In any case, thanks a million. I only had to customize each of them with paths basically.

Comment: the first solution was a bit lengthy compared to the new one and also gave wrong results, means after copy there was f.e. subdir aa_aa containing aa_aa.dito, bb_bb.dito and cc_cc_dito instead of only aa_aa.dito !

Comment: I saw that later, I went back to the first one to play around because I'm wondering if I can get this to work on files within folders in multiple levels. Will post more as an update to the original.